# ZeroMQ C++ to C# communication

Tags: c#, c++, zeromq

My current project involves building a high speed framework for communications across different OSs and remote systems for computer vision applications where the various components communicate using ZeroMQ sockets. This works fine in Standard C++ (Non-Cli).

I have recently found a use-case where I need to interface with an application coded in C#. Having compiled and run the "Hello World" example from the guide (On localhost) with clrzmq 2.2.2. I cannot get the two programs to communicate (One in C++ one in C#).

The C# server receives a request from the C++ client but nothing happens after that, it just seems to hang, which would indicate a problem with the C# response. Replacing the C# server with a C++ one compiled from the guide works fine.

Does anybody have any experience of getting C++ apps to talk to .NET using ZMQ? I would be grateful for any help, as this is not covered in any documentation I have been able to locate.

Comment: Communicating between different languages, OSes, hardware etc. should make no difference to 0mq. If you post us the absolute minimum of code that produces the unexpected behavior, we will better help you with your problem.

Comment: I can't help, I'm afraid, but I can confirm that you are not alone. I've recently looked at using clrzmq and noticed the same hanging problem when connecting from a Python peer. I was just toying around, so I didn't investigate far enough to discover the reason.

Comment: That's what I thought, I know it's best to serialise across platforms ie. Windows to Linux, and I have been using Google protocol buffers for this but this particular issue is just using the minimum code from the ZMQ tutorial page code as follows:

Comment: c++ client: http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:hwclient

Comment: c++ client: http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:hwclient, the C# I got from the downloaded files. I've just tried the other way around using C++ server and a C# client which gives the error: Expression: map/set iterators incompatible. I'll look this up as it could give some indication as to why this isn't working.

Comment: Thanks Marcelo, it's good to know I'm not alone. Guess it could be a problem with the clrzmq bindings then?

Comment: Although it could equally be the supplied code in the tutorial.

Comment: I've had a look and this would appear to be a .dll error which would indicate a problem with the C# implementation. I will raise this as a potential bug. For information, I have tried running the C# examples using C# -> C# which also works fine so it does seem to be an interop issue. I am using VS2010 Ultimate on Win7 x64 to compile the C#, building in 32bit mode.

Comment: It is open source.  You got the code, you got a debugger, find the bug and submit the patch back to the project.  If you don't want to do it yourself then there's a way around that as well: iMatix appears to be making a living at providing technical support.

Comment: I got a C# server to work quite well with a Python client.

Comment: Hans, I really do know what you mean, but I'm still studying, rather than looking at OSS as part of a business. It's a steep learning curve and so that is why I am asking for help on this forum.

Comment: My particular issue is that if you make a guide which I have found incredibly helpful for learning ZMQ over C++, you would expect the C# example to work with the C++ example. Don't get me wrong, I'm not being critical here, but when you're learning you look at examples first and if they don't work you try everything you can to ensure you have followed the instruction provided, and if everything else fails, you ask for help. That is what I have done here. As soon as I am more competent with C# I will do as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks zmpq, that takes zmq out of the picture. It's clearly that the code provided in the guide doesn't support interop and I need to look through the API docs to build an interop version. I only did this as a test before coding and thought best to ask some people with real knowledge about the subject before proceeding. I think it is only reasonable that after I get this working, I relay my findings to ZMQ so it may help others who are finding the same issue.

Comment: You may want to edit your post and talk a bit about the topology you're trying to do. Also indicate which is the producer and which is the consumer. Which order you're starting them in, etc.

Answer (score 1):

That is likely to be an application bug. We have a program like that running without issues. C# to c++.

Comment: Solved: After debugging, I still couldn't work out what the problem was so I started from scratch, rebuilding the libraries from source using zeromq-2.1.11 for C++ and the NuGet clrzmq .NET bindings v.2.2.3. for C#. Having tried the example again, it now works perfectly. Guess I had a corrupt or mismatched library in there somewhere. Thank you for your help.